# Problem with updating due to obsolete package versions.

Tags: 12.04, updates

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. When I started the update manager I received this message:

```
The problem cannot be reported:

You have some obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages  
and check if the problem still occurs:

jockey-common, busybox-initramfs, coreutils, dbus, initscripts, libapt-inst1.4,  
libapt-pkg4.12, libc-bin, libc6, libdbus-1-3, libexpat1, libgcrypt11, libglib2.0-0,  
libgnutls26, libgssapi-krb5-2, libk5crypto3, libkrb5-3, libkrb5support0, libldap-2.4-2,   
libpolkit-agent-1-0, libpolkit-backend-1-0, libpolkit-gobject-1-0, libsasl2-2, libsqlite3-0,  
libssl1.0.0, libtasn1-3, libudev0, libxcb1, lsb-base, mountall, multiarch-support, openssl,   
passwd, perl-base, policykit-1, python2.7, python2.7-minimal, sysv-rc, sysvinit-utils, tzdata,   
udev, upstart
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  Thank you.
David

Comment: Just run update via comandline, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 13):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Since autoclean removes packages that are no longer available from configured software sources, you may want to move the `sudo apt-get autoclean` step until right after the `sudo apt-get update` step.

- Clean: clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package
  files. It removes everything but the lock file from
  `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`. When
  APT is used as a dselect method, clean is run automatically. Those
  who do not use dselect will likely want to run apt-get clean from
  time to time to free up disk space.
- Autoclean: Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of
  retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes
  package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely
  useless. This allows a cache to be maintained over a long period
  without it growing out of control. The configuration option
  APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from being
  erased if it is set to off.
- Autoremove: is used to remove packages that were automatically
  installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no
  longer needed.

[See manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)

Comment: Could you please go into some more detail about "... you may want to move the sudo apt-get autoclean step until right after the sudo apt-get update step." Doesn't autoclean only remove .debs from /var/cache/apt/archives for packages that are no longer installed?

Comment: And what if that doesn't resolve the problem? I still have problems going unreported because tzdata is obsolete but there's no such upgrade available.

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't help either